# Comma Separated File, appending encrypted charter instead of new line

Tags: php, csv

I am creating a comma separated file, that appends encrypted character at the end of each line instead of starting the next line in a new line?

```
        $inner_exported_header_array[] = 'ID';
        $inner_exported_header_array[] = 'First Name';

        $exported_customers_arr [] = $inner_exported_header_array;
        foreach ($_list AS $row) {
            $inner_exported_array = array();
            $inner_exported_array[] = $row['id'];
            $inner_exported_array[] = $row['v_first_name'];

            $exported_customers_arr[] = $inner_exported_array;
        }

        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-Type: text/plain");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");

        outputCSV($exported_customers_arr); 


function outputCSV($data) {
$outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");

function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
    fputcsv($filehandler, $vals); // add parameters if you want
}

array_walk($data, "__outputCSV", $outstream);
fclose($outstream);
}
```

Output is showing:

```
"ID","First Name"[special character not copied here]1,Testname
```

But if would be:

```
"ID","First Name"
1,Testname
```

Any thought, that our new line should be in a new line rather than inserting special characters at end of line ans starting new line from where the first line ends?

Comment: Random guess: "\n" vs. "\r\n" problem? Can you look at the result in a hex editor and tell us what exactly that character is? The data is probably fine, just whatever you use to view it doesn't like this particular newline sequence.

Comment: I had tried to copy the character here, but not showing, let me tell you with hex editor

Comment: @deceze: hex editor shwoing the character [0A]

Comment: 0xA is the character for newline, use trim() to remove it as I mention in my reply below

Comment: @FilipposKarapetis: let me check it plz

Comment: @deceze: If I open the .txt file in wordpad and just same the file without any changes, then all records shown properly in new line, but if we not change any thing then showing the next line record appened the the previous line

Comment: And in what program are the newlines messed up?

Comment: @deceze: I am importing to MYOB, but the problem of new line occured

Comment: Can you specify to MYOB to expect a different newline character upon import?

Comment: no, their is just one option for file format, either tab or comma, but not for new line.

Comment: That's kind of a problem then. The easiest solution may be to simply read the file in and replace every `"\n"` with `"\r\n"`.

Comment: hmmm, let me try it plz

Comment: @deceze: Solved the issue, by your tip!! please post the answer so that I will accept it!!!(Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from the comments:

The easiest solution may be to simply read the file in and replace every `"\n"` with `"\r\n"`. The consumer of the file expects different line endings.

Answer (score 1):

What are these characters? Seems like they're coming from your database, somehow? These "special" characters seem to contain newline (i.e. \n), which messes up your output.

I suggest checking the value of the last character of your problematic field using PHP's ord() function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

You could clean your CSV output using PHP's trim() function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

trim() also clears newline, which should solve your issue, if applied to the output of each field, i.e change this:

```
$inner_exported_array[] = $row['v_first_name'];
```

to:

```
$inner_exported_array[] = trim($row['v_first_name']);
```

Comment: I have used the trim function that same character is showing, and each next line is started where previous line ends